# ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting the following error when I try to register a new user for my app in production. I have read through all of the other stackoverflow questions that have the same error, and I've tried all of their solutions, but none of them have worked for me so far.

The error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

I have this code set correctly with my own app name in my production.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
```

Here is the complete production.rb file:

```
Blocipedia::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.cache_classes = true


  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true


  config.serve_static_assets = false


  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = false


  config.assets.digest = true


  config.assets.version = '1.0'


  config.log_level = :info


  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify


  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
end
```

I double checked that I have Sendgrid configured as an add-on in Heroku. My keys and passwords are correct.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: I am using Devise for user authentication.  I'm not sure exactly which file is the mailer template file that this error is referring to, but I'm guessing it's the new registration view and then the mailer confirmation instructions view that would be related to this error, is that right?  Here they are:

new registration view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter email" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password confirmation" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and confirmation instructions view:

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

Here is the entire error trace log:

```
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
2014-09-24T23:38:38.136606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_up" host=blocipedia.herokuapp.com request_id=f52c96a7-014c-4667-b1b3-93e8b47e4364 fwd="70.197.237.94" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=850
2014-09-24T23:38:48.250414+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 70.197.237.94 at 2014-09-24 23:38:48 +0000
2014-09-24T23:38:48.347819+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349962+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349966+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349969+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2014-09-24T23:38:48.347813+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349959+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349972+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349974+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_erb___2772878935586456441_70136789435480'
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349977+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-09-24T23:38:48.252507+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2014-09-24T23:38:48.349953+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

Comment: Are the emails being sent as a background job or during the request? If it's a background job (e.g. running a rake task via Heroku Scheduler), ensure the environment is being set properly to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your config looks right for the host.

---

**Solution**

Enable `ActionMailer` settings for the production environment:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:           '587',
  authentication: :plain,
  user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  domain:         'heroku.com',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

These settings can be specified in `config/environments/production.rb`, or in an initializer script.

If using an initializer script, ensure that any `if` block guards that are dependent on environment include production, for example, in `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
    ... # ActionMailer config goes here.
end
```

---

**Original answer suggestions**

There are only three possibilities that are springing to mind right now that might be the problem. These may not be right, but here goes.

Where is the error message from? By running `heroku logs`? From your terminal on your local environment? If it's your local environment, check your `config/environments/development.rb` file (and test.rb while you're there maybe) has the host option configured.

Perhaps the change hasn't made it to the production environment, or the production environment isn't being run on heroku.

You can check `heroku config` doesn't have a `RAILS_ENV` variable set, or if it does, ensure it's set to `production`. (Run `heroku config` in your app's directory).

Check that the latest code is committed and pushed to Heroku:

```
git status
git add . # Only if there are unstaged changes
git commit -m "Message describing changes"
git push heroku master
```

If there are no changes that needed to be pushed to Heroku, then try `heroku restart`.

Comment: I am using Devise to send out the confirmation instructions email, so that means it's during the request, correct? I found the error message by running heroku logs in terminal.  I ran heroku config, as you suggested, and my RAILS_ENV is set to production.  My latest code has been committed, and I finally tried heroku restart.  I'm still getting the same error, though.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at the heroku logs error, and read the first few lines of it. Is there a template file with a line number specified in there? If yes, that's the source of the problem. You can confirm it is by commenting/removing the line. You might want to include the entire error trace in the question too.

Comment: I will now add the entire error trace in the question.  It refers to line 5 in the confirmation_instructions file. I don't understand how this could be the problem though since Devise generated everything for me and I didn't change the code.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Is default_url_options being set anywhere else in the app? Perhaps the setting in production.rb is being wiped out elsewhere. Search the codebase for `default_url_options`.

Comment: One more idea - are you on a git branch, and have the changes been merged into master?

Comment: Yes, you can find my code at https://github.com/valeriemettler/Blocipedia.  I did a search for default_url_options, right now and it came back as none found.

Comment: The setup_mail.rb initializer ought to be enabled for production too, currently it'll only work in development. I don't know if that'd cause this error but it'd stop mail from sending.

Comment: Not having setup_mail.rb initializer enabled for production was the cause of the error! Problem solved! Thank you, Eliot!!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a `:host` option to `confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)`, e.g.

```
confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, host: 'myapp.herokuapp.com')
```

(Though this doesn't feel right passing the hard-coded production URL in a template, it may get you one step closer to figuring out the issue)

Comment: Eliot, do I add that code as an addition to my other code in the production.rb file? (I'm a newbie!) Thanks!

Comment: It's a modification to the confirmation instructions view template you added to the question.

Comment: Thanks again, now I tried using the above code and now in heroku logs in terminal it is showing the following error:   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 123ms, Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)): along with a long list of vendor file names. What would this mean?

Comment: Is there a more detailed error below that? If not, try another request. Also try it in your development environment to make sure that at least it's working there first.

Comment: No, there are no other references to errors.  Just a very long list of vendor file names.  I've tried it three times.  Each time it comes back the same.  I also just tried it again in development, and it works perfectly there.